# Loop and delay infinite CSS3 animation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to add and remove classes on animated elements to create a stagger/delay effect so once the animation is completed, it adds an animation out class, then once that is completed it restarts the process.

I am using animate.css for the animations.

I have created a jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3ozfgrh2/

As you can see it plays out the first 'loop' fine but then it removes/adds the classes too early/off.

```
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
$('.sticker').on(animationEnd, function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('bounceIn').addClass('bounceOut').on(animationEnd, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.removeClass('bounceOut').addClass('bounceIn');
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code is not working as you expect because you are trying to attach 2 different behaviours to the same "onAnimationEnd" event.

You can avoid this confusion by "unhooking" any events from the animationEnd event with `.off().` 
before attaching the new behaviour using `.on()`.

I've split your code in to two separate functions so that you can set them up to continue firing continuously in a loop.

```js
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

$('.sticker').on(animationEnd, addBounceOut);

function addBounceOut() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('bounceIn').addClass('bounceOut').off(animationEnd).on(animationEnd, addBounceIn);
}

function addBounceIn() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.removeClass('bounceOut').addClass('bounceIn').off(animationEnd).on(animationEnd, addBounceOut);
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.sticker {
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 12vw;
  height: 12vw;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.sticker.one {
  background-color: orange;
  top: 7%;
  left: 15%;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.sticker.two {
  background-color: green;
  top: 14%;
  right: 11%;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.sticker.three {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 43%;
  right: 22%;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.sticker.four {
  background-color: red;
  top: 60%;
  left: 10%;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="sticker one animated bounceIn" href="#"></a>
<a class="sticker two animated bounceIn" href="#"></a>
<a class="sticker three animated bounceIn" href="#"></a>
<a class="sticker four animated bounceIn" href="#"></a>
```